# find for a substring in a string

Tags: javascript, function

my problem: I have such a string

B30(XY)=.13-B5(XY) ins A701(XY) and I have to check if there is such a combination in this string (in this example):

.13

This 13 represents a year. So, it is also possible this number combination is .12 or
.17 or
.01 or
.00 ect.

I have no idea how can I check this dot and than two numbers in a given string

Thanks

Josef

Answer (score 6):

Simple regular expression:

```
"B30(XY)=.13-B5(XY) ins A701(XY)".match(/\.(\d{2})/)[1]
```

- `\.` - find a "."
- `(` - start of the capture group 
  *`\d{2}` - followed by two numbers
- `)` - end of the capture group

Comment: This will match .133 too (actually, part of it)? Maybe to add boundary?

Comment: @sinisake How would it match .133? It has a limit of two numbers like OP said in the question...

Comment: Part: https://regex101.com/r/JFO4Or/2 but i guess that's not big problem, if there is limit... :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers.

But the problem: A year declaration like .133 is also true.

I have to check :
.13 is true
.133 is false
.1 is false

Thanks again.

Josef

Comment: You should add it to your question. Would this work for you? https://regex101.com/r/JFO4Or/4